# About Ruby Gsub

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

```
params[:hello] # => "Some params value"

hello = params[:hello]
hello.gsub!("whatever","")

params[:hello] # => ""
```

I don't understand, can someone please explain why the `params[:hello]` gets modified by the `gsub!` ? I expected the `hello` string to be modified, but not the `params` hash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hello` and `params[:hello]` are references to the same string. In ruby (as in java and python among others) assignment does not copy the value, it just stores another reference to the same value in the assigned-to variable. So unless you explicitly copy the string before modifying it (using `dup`) any changes to the string will affect all other references to the string.

Answer (score 2):

There are two versions of `String#gsub` available

```
a= "abc" # => "abc"
b= a.gsub("b", "2") # "a2c"
a # => "abc"
c= a.gsub!("c", "3") # => "ab3"
a # => "ab3"
```

`String#gsub!` modifies the original string and returns a reference to it.
`String#gsub` does not modify the original and makes the replacement on a copy.

It is a common ruby idiom to name methods which modify the object with a `!`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it to be modified, you need to clone it, like:

```
hello = params[:hello].clone
```

The way you're doing it now, you have a reference to it, not a copy.